# Do the Stoic virtues have any order of ethical importance?

Tags: stoicism

Do the Stoic virtues (wisdom, justice, courage, and moderation) have a specific order of ethical importance? If there is a order of ethical importance, then is there any specific reasoning to that order?

Comment: Welcome to SE. An interesting question. It would help if you could clarify what you mean by "order". Do you mean an order of ethical importance, or an order in which they should be acquired or what? Also, it may make a difference if you asking what the stoics said, or what we should think now?

Comment: @LudwigV Thank you for your questions. I meant if virtues have any ethical importance. I have updated the question.